# How set new value for the annotation from the command line?

Tags: java, command-line, terminal, cucumber

My task: run autotests from the command line, passing the tag name as an argument.

My class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        glue = {"com.company.stepDefs", "com.company.stepdefs"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
        tags = {"@TEST1"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"}
)

public class CucumberTest { }
```

I need to pass the new value for the parameter `tags`.

1. What do I need to do for this task in Java-code? How to set my new value for the annotation?
2. What command do I need on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to set my new value for the annotation?

Through command line argument.

> 2. What command do I need on the command line?

mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@TEST1"

Documentation is your friend:

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/

Comment: What should the annotation look like then?

`@CucumberOptions(
        tags = {args[0]}
)`

the compiler swears at `args[0]`

Comment: Annotations is just sort of metadata, attached to class, so you cannot dynamically pass values to them. But you can 'instruct' annotation parser to replace value during processing of this annotation. This one "@TEST1" is an instruction, means that '@TEST1' text will be substituted with argument passed from command line.

Comment: Correctly, I realized that I do not need to make any changes to Java code to solve this problem?